# Multi Condition/Complex Query for CSU/UC requirements

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a query that checks if a student has completed the A-G UC/CSU requirements when they graduate from High School. (Requirements seen here: http://www.ucop.edu/agguide/a-g-requirements/)

We have a field in our DB that designates which courses are in specific categories. For example we designate specific History courses taken at the HS as the "A" category, "B" Category, etc. The problem is that it varies, for example, the history can have two years of world history and one year of US history OR can have one semester of Government, one semester of US history, and one year of world/history class(see A-G requirements).

My initial thought is to pull the classes the student has taken for each category (that is a passing grade of "C") and then count the number of classes each student has taken for each category and if they have the minimum class amount then check it as them completing that Category requirements. This query is pretty complex/tricky, so I am open to suggestions on how to go about doing this.

Thanks!

Comment: do you have a table that assigns a "weight" to each class?  eg "A" category = 1.0, "B" category = .5

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be very helpful.  A SQL Fiddle would be even better.

Comment: No, there aren't any weights assigned to the classes. They of course have credits for each class and varies depending on the class but the credits aren't used to determine the A-G requirements. It's basically class defined for each category .